# NSString pointer passed to function... not keeping the value I set

Tags: cocoa, pointers, parameter-passing

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I've also tried setting `s1..3` in `foo` by using:

`s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[filepaths objectAtIndex:0]];`

Context below:

```
void foo(NSString *s1, NSString *s2, NSString *s3){
    //assign long string to NSString *fps
    //...
    //break fps into smaller bits
    NSArray *filepaths = [fps componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    //the above worked! now let's assign them to the pointers
    s1 = [filepaths objectAtIndex:0];
    //repeat for s2 and s3
    NSLog(@"%@",s1); //it worked! we're done in this function
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    NSString *s1 = nil; //s2 and s3 as well
    foo(s1,s2,s3); //this should work
    NSLog(@"%@",s1); //UH OH, this is null!
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You are passing in pointers to objects which can be mutated locally.  You are **not** changing the original objects, as you might think from plain C.

If you want to use this method (which I would *not* recommend - it's really odd to see in Cocoa except in the case of `NSError`), you would have something like:

```
void foo(NSString **s1, NSString **s2, NSString **s3) {
    *s1 = [filepaths objectAtIndex:0]; // etc.
}
```

You would then pass in `&s1` as the argument.

This will, of course, clobber whatever was in `s1`, potentially cause memory leaks, thread unsafety, etc., unless you are really careful.  Which is why I say you usually won't do this.

Comment: It's a short, relatively simple command line program, but the Foundation and Scripting Bridge frameworks come in handy, so here it is in Obj-C.  Also, blame this on a few years passing since the last time I needed or thought to pass pointers around.

Comment: @ray Nothing wrong with writing a command line program in Objective-C; in fact I recommended that to someone just this morning on a mailing list.  I would just recommend you flip your thinking around: have the method return an NSArray that contains your strings.  Much simpler, clearer, less likely to cause problems elsewhere.

Comment: @ray I'm not 100% sure, but I think the convention of return-by-reference in C is due in large measure to the near total lack of collection primitives in C (even an array is just a glorified pointer), a non-issue in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

Functions take a local copy of their arguments, so you're modifying a copy of the `NSString*` not the original. This is called "pass by value". What you want is "pass by reference," which looks like this:

```
void foo(NSString** s1) {
    if(s1) *s1 = @"Different string";
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    NSString* s1 = nil;
    foo(&s1);
    NSLog(@"%@", s1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It boils down to how well you understand pointers in C. It would be a good idea to read up on the "address of" operator `&`, and the dereference operator `*`, and just C pointers in general.